# Possible values for integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to answer the following question:

What are all possible values of the integral:

$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+1}dz$

When $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ is a path s.t. $\gamma (1)=1,\gamma(0)=0$ and $\gamma(t)\ne -1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.

My attempt:

$\gamma *\gamma^-$ is a closed path in $\mathbb{C}$ that doesn't contain any singular points, the function is holomorphic, so I can apply the Residue Theorem. I've calculated the residue and came to conclusion:

$\int_{\gamma*\gamma^-}\frac{1}{z+1}dz=2\pi i\cdot k,\quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now I know that:

$\int_{\gamma*\gamma^-}\frac{1}{z+1}dz=\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+1}dz+\int_{\gamma^-}\frac{1}{z+1}dz$

and I'm not sure how to procceed.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The given closed path meeting your requirements either contains the unique pole of $\frac{1}{1 + z}$ in its interior or not. If it doesn't, the integral is zero by Cauchy's theorem. If it does, then the integral is $2\pi ik$, where $k$ is the winding number of your curve around $-1$.